# Clear the cache always that I refresh the page

Tags: browser, firefox

Im wondering if there is any way to clear the cache always that I refresh the page (F5) in FF 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> = Reload (override cache)

Firefox keyboard shortcuts:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly